# Module not found when drag and drop Python file

Tags: python, windows, drag-and-drop, xlsxwriter

I have a Python script which user's drag and drop KML files into for easy use. It takes the dropped file as sys.arg[1]. When entered into the command line as `myScript.py Location.kml` everything works fine. But when I drag and drop the file in an error is thrown saying `no module named xlsxwriter`. xlsxwriter is in the same folder as my Python script in another folder named Packages. Why does it work for the command line but not when dragged and dropped? Is there some trick I am missing?

Comment: So you have a your script and a directory which has xlswriter inside?

Comment: @PabloPalácios Yes, the main folder has three items: the script, a KML file, and another folder named Packages. xlsxwriter is in Packages.

Comment: The script's directory should be `sys.path[0]`, so you should be able to import packages located there. The `Packages` subdirectory shouldn't be in `sys.path`, not by default at least. You can add it manually: `script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__));` `package_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'Packages');` `sys.path.insert(1, package_dir)`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks that worked! It was also because I was setting my path for the module with `sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+'/Packages')` while it should have been set with `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))+'/Packages')`

Comment: I suggest inserting at index 1 instead of appending. This gives your private packages precedence over the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to erkysun this issue was solved! eryksun's solution worked perfectly and I found another reason it wasn't working. This was because when I dragged and dropped the file into the python script then ran `os.getcwd()` no matter where the file was it returned `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. To counteract this wherever I had `os.getcwd()` I changed it to `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` and then it worked!